# Error when editing membership batch

Tags: joomla

I am using CiviCRM v5.57.0 on Joomla 4.2.6.

I have created all my contacts and have set up prices for each of 3 classes of member.

When I commence the first batch membership fee entry, I get the following error:

count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given

What is this? How do I correct it?

---

When I switch on debugging I get the following warning:
Warning: Undefined array key "localTasks" in /homepages/33/d128624839/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Joomla/BMDLHS_Jan23/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%EA/EAA/EAA96A89%%joomla.tpl.php on line 56

Then when I select "Enter Records" the Joomla error gets displayed.

Comment: I believe that I may have hit a previously unreported bug.
Having been pointed at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php, it looks as though the error experienced is due to me using PHP 8.0.27. As shown above my Joomla version is 4.2.6 and the CiviCRM version is 5.57.1.

I did look at the demo site, but that is using Joomla 3.9 which is now deprecated.

Comment: I have now tried the demo which is using Joomla 4, but is also only using PHP 7, which shows a warning about imminent deprecation. This bug is certainly present with PHP 8 as shown.